# Python Requests Ignores Path Portion of Filename When Uploading Files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I am trying to use Python Requests and boto3 to upload JSON files using a pre-signed POST url.  But `requests` ignores the path portion of the `key`.

Here is a minimal, working example:

```
import boto3, requests, json, tempfile

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = "some_bucket"
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name, "${filename}", ExpiresIn=3600)

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

content = {"hello" : "world"}
json_data = json.dumps(content).encode('utf-8')
key = "this/path/is/ignored/buthisworks.json"

with open(tmp.name, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(content, outfile)

with open(tmp.name, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'file': (key, f)}
    response = requests.post(response['url'], data=response['fields'], files=files)
```

S3 receives an object named `buthisworks.json` instead of getting an object named `this/path/is/ignored/buthisworks.json`

The documentation for [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [generate_presigned_post](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html#generating-a-presigned-url-to-upload-a-file) do not show examples where a path is used.

Perhaps there is a different way to accomplish this? Would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I suspect file uploads deliberately ignore paths, as a safety measure.

Comment: You are probably right.  I figured out a solution and posted an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74117189/262677

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out! `generate_presigned_post()` returns an object with two dictionaries, `url` and `fields`, the latter which contains a key called `key` which can be set to `this/path/is/ignored/buthisworks.json`

Sending that request with the modified `key` field works!